# SQL - How to backup a database and export as a MDF file with MS SQL 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, database, mdf

I have created a database "test" with some tables in MS SQL Server 2008 R2 (i.e. MS SQL Server Management Studio).

Now, I need to export this database as a MDF file.

What should I do?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the MDF file?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

If you mean that you want to be able to attach the database on another server, then this is what you can do:

1. detach the database (right click the database and click `Detach`)
2. copy the mdf and ldf files to your backup location
3. attach the database (right click `Databases` and click `Attach`)

**This is the path where you will find MDF file:**

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\
```

Comment: Where I can find the MDF? Thank you

Comment: In Management Studio, right click the database and click Properties.  Go to the `Files` page. You'll find the location under `Path`.

Comment: What a brilliant answer, dude!

Comment: Why do you need to detach first?  What if the db is in production and why not just go to the directory and copy the files already found there?

Answer (score 2):

right-click on database from Management Studio -> Detach. Then you have the MDF file you can export to wherever you want :)

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way is to create a `.bak` file from SQL Server .

Right click on the database => `Task` => `Back Up` -> Choose the database in `Source` , and hit `OK` .

Comment: So... how do you make it into an MDF, then?

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is a replica of your SQLEXPRESS/MDF local file- on a remote server (SQL Server 2005)

You can right click in the **"Server Explorer"** on your db.mdf file and press **"Publish to provider..."**

You can choose a variety of compatibilities with SQL Server 2005, 2008, etc.

The output is a **.sql query file ..**

Came across this question and thought this would be a good alternative answer, since I got here by searching for the exact same thing!

Comment: Unfortunately the SQL generation is not the same as a MDF; a MDF can be attached directly.

Answer (score 1):

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\

**This is the path where you will find MDF file**

Answer (score 1):

If you are in Visual Studio, go to **SQL Server Object Explorer**. Find the database you want, right click and select properties. In the properties tab, look for **Data File**, next to it will be the location for your mdf file.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, its easier to use the commands sp_detach_db ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188031.aspx)) and sp_attach_db ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179877.aspx)). I was trying to attach a database that was offline when detached and SQL Server Management Studio (2014) kept crashing when I used the Attach option from the right-click context menu. The commands worked - hope this saves someone some time.

**NOTE:** Run SSMS as an administrator if you see an access denied while trying to execute the attach command

Answer (score 0):

Go to the path C:\Users\your pc name
then you will find mdf , ldf file here